# Showing CustomDialog as modal dialog and get result (mahapps)

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, customdialog, mahapps.metro

I have a class which creates `SimpleDialog` (now `CustomDialog`) with custom contents. So far I'm successful in showing it & closing it. But how to return its return to parent window? Just like how `ShowDialog` method does? The code so far is,

```
    internal void fnShowDialog(MainWindow parent)
    {
        SimpleDialog dialog = new SimpleDialog();
        StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();

        Label block = new Label() { Content = "custom message" };
        TextBlock block1 = new TextBlock() { Text = "custom message", FontSize = 22 };
        Button button = new Button() { Content = "close" };
        button.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                parent.HideMetroDialogAsync((BaseMetroDialog)dialog);
            };
        panel.Children.Add(block);
        panel.Children.Add(block1);
        panel.Children.Add(button);
        dialog.DialogBody = panel;            

        parent.ShowMetroDialogAsync((BaseMetroDialog)dialog);
    }
```

I need to know the result of this dialog for further precessing accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get the dialog's result in the `Click` event handler, the same place you call `HideMetroDialogAsync`.

Comment: But in that click event handler, when I do the following `var result = await this.HideMetroDialogAsync((myDialog);` I get the error: `Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable`. Maybe, I misunderstood your suggestion. Any suggestion?

Comment: I didn't say to get the result from `HideMetroDialogAsync`, as it returns a plain `Task`. Have a look at @mahdi-ataollahi above, his answer's better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Every Form has DialogResult property. You can set them on some event and then check the enum value of them in your dialog objects after closing the Form.

BaseMetroDialog could have DialogResult property which would be visible to parent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple asynchronous process:

1. You should use `await` keyword to get the result:

   ```
   var result = await parent.ShowMetroDialogAsync((BaseMetroDialog)dialog);
   ```

Don't forget to `return result;` at the end of the method.

2. Change your method definition to return this result like this:

   ```
   internal async Task<MessageDialogResult> fnShowDialog(MainWindow parent)
   ```

This is the full method:

```
internal async Task<MessageDialogResult> fnShowDialog(MainWindow parent)
{
    SimpleDialog dialog = new SimpleDialog();
    StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();

    Label block = new Label() { Content = "custom message" };
    TextBlock block1 = new TextBlock() { Text = "custom message", FontSize = 22 };
    Button button = new Button() { Content = "close" };
    button.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            parent.HideMetroDialogAsync((BaseMetroDialog)dialog);
        };
    panel.Children.Add(block);
    panel.Children.Add(block1);
    panel.Children.Add(button);
    dialog.DialogBody = panel;            

    var result = await parent.ShowMetroDialogAsync((BaseMetroDialog)dialog);
    return result;
}
```

3. You can use this method with an `await` like this:

   ```
   var result = awiat fnShowDialog(parent);
   if(result == ...)
   {...}
   ```